# Where is the PHP binary after building PHP from source?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, build

I just build php 8.0.15 from source with `./configure` and `make`.

It ran through without errors, but I can't find the generated php binary.

Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiled binaries will be available in the ./sapi directory. To immediately run the PHP CLI, for example, call the ./sapi/cli/php binary.

Comment: /sapi: No such file or directory

Comment: I just compiled php version 8.0.15, and I had the 'sapi' folder, inside the 'php-src' folder. Are you sure there is no errors when compiling with 'make' ?

Comment: Ok found it, I thought you mean `/sapi/cli/php` but you mean `location/of/build/folder/sapi/cli/php`

Comment: Yeah, that was a little unclear :-) Happy you got it working.